# Is it possible to move the Spring beans xml file outside the WAR?

Tags: java, spring, war, applicationcontext

I'm trying to move the Spring Beans location outside the WAR by adjusting web.xml. My web.xml contains this:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/intu-1.0.0-beans.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

I would like to specify a path that's outside the WAR.
I also tried manually loading the beans, but I didn't get that to work for the following reason (the rest of this post is about this): I do want to load *some* beans automatically. Because otherwise the application won't start. The project is a SOAP-service. I have another file, rts-application-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-camel.xml" />

    <jaxws:endpoint id="Intu"
        implementor="nl.billinghouse.intu.service.Intu"
        wsdlLocation="wsdl/intu.wsdl"
        endpointName="tns:IntuPort"
        serviceName="tns:Intu"
        xmlns:tns="http://intu"
        xmlns:ns1="http://www.skidata.com/projects/svp/parking/v4">
        <jaxws:features>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
        </jaxws:features>
        <jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="exceptionMessageCauseEnabled" value="false" />
            <entry key="faultStackTraceEnabled" value="false" />
        </jaxws:properties> 
    </jaxws:endpoint>
</beans>
```

It will construct an Intu, I would then load the other beans file in the constructor of Intu.java. I have the following other version of web.xml:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/rts-application-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <!--<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/intu-1.0.0-beans.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>-->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

but because of the listener it automatically also tries to load intu-1.0.0-beans.xml from the WAR (I think by default). When I remove that listener, it also won't load rts-application-context.xml and therefore not constuct the Intu.

EDIT: the error I'm getting when it tries to load the beans from WAR where I hope it wouldn't, is:

```
jun 02, 2015 3:55:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
jun 02, 2015 3:55:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/intu-1.0.0-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/intu-1.0.0-beans.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1120)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1678)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/intu-1.0.0-beans.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file:` path with a spring import tag:

```
<import resource="file:/home/user/spring-beans.xml"/>
```

in your `rts-application-context.xml`

Comment: When I do that, it might load the file, but it's still (also) trying to load the intu-1.0.0-beans.xml from the WAR. I have searched in all possible ways in my code, but I can find nowhere where that might happen. The error I'm getting is: parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/intu-1.0.0-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/intu-1.0.0-beans.xml]

Comment: Can you post the full stack of the error, that would give a hint on whats loading the intu..xml file

Comment: From your stack the error is coming from web.xml config. Please check if the correct war is being deployed (having web.xml with commented config). 1 way to verify is to add an error to web.xml and confirm that the server shows that.

Comment: I will try that and get back later. By the way I'm using eclipse.

Comment: hmm, I placed the file it's looking for in C:\tomcat7\webapps\IntuRTS\WEB-INF and it still keeps giving the same error.